# How can I create 2 forms simultaneously in just one view in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have two forms in the same template('index.html'), one form is to contact me and when the user send the form I receive an email. And the Other form is to 'register' in the system, so then i can enter in contact. The problem is that the two forms are in the same template and I want put them in the same view.

This is the way that my view is.

```
class IndexView(FormView):
template_name = 'index.html'
form_class = ContatoForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['servicos'] = Servico.objects.order_by('?').all()
    context['funcionarios'] = Funcionario.objects.order_by('?').all()
    context['portfolios'] = Portfolio.objects.order_by('?').all()
    context['testimonials'] = Testimonial.objects.order_by('?').all()

    return context

def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
    form.send_mail()
    messages.success(self.request, 'E-mail enviado com sucesso')
    return super(IndexView, self).form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)

def form_invalid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
    messages.error(self.request, 'Erro ao enviar e-mail')

    return super(IndexView, self).form_invalid(form, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is the modelform that i want to put in the view

```
class RegistroModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Registro
    fields = ['nome', 'email', 'phone', 'area']
```